# Create a dictionary Permission denied

Tags: clickhouse

I need help with a permission error while accessing a freshly created dictionary.

My source file for a dictionary is as follows:

```
$ ls -l /root/organization.csv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 clickhouse clickhouse 154 Jul  7 14:56 /root/organization.csv

$ cat /root/organization.csv
1,"a0001","研发部"
2,"a0002","产品部"
3,"a0003","数据部"
4,"a0004","测试部"
5,"a0005","运维部"
6,"a0006","规划部"
7,"a0007","市场部"
```

I create my dictionary as follows:

```
CREATE DICTIONARY test_flat_dict
(
    id UInt64,
    code String,
    name String
)
PRIMARY KEY id
SOURCE(FILE(PATH '/root/organization.csv' FORMAT CSV))
LAYOUT(HASHED())
LIFETIME(0);
```

Then I'm trying to test a dictionary by a simple SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM test_flat_dict
```

But I'm getting the exception:

```
Received exception from server (version 21.6.3):
Code: 156. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Failed to load dictionary 'eeedf011-4a41-4337-aeed-f0114a414337': std::exception. Code: 1001, type: std::__1::__fs::filesystem::filesystem_error, e.what() = filesystem error: in canonical: Permission denied [/root/organization.csv] [""],
```

What might be wrong with my dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stated on [ClickHouse documentation](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/dictionaries/external-dictionaries/external-dicts-dict-sources/#dicts-external_dicts_dict_sources-local_file):

```
When dictionary with source FILE is created via DDL command (CREATE 
DICTIONARY ...), the source file needs to be located in user_files
directory, to prevent DB users accessing arbitrary file on ClickHouse
node.
```

I would doubt that ClickHouse has the ability to retrieve files from the root home folder, even if your file has 777 mode.

So I would propose you put the data file under `./user_files` folder (it's in the root of ClickHouse data folder).

Comment: Thank u,the `user_files_path` of the config.xml should be followed.